# Office Word add-in JS - how to avoid actions taken by the add-in to appear in the Undo history

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm developing a Word add-in that sends parts of the text to an API, and then performs certain modifications on the document, such as: highlighting, text insertion, and so on. This works fine, however all of the individual changes appear in the undo stack, which makes it difficult for users to go back to the previous state of the document.

Is there any way to make that actions taken by the add-in:

- Appear as a single atomic action?
- Do not appear at all?

I'm using the API as linked by the following resource: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You could request such a feature in [Office developer suggestion box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), but I think it is unlikely to be changed. Undo is a vital feature of Word and it is unlikely that Microsoft would enable add-ins to effectively disable or weaken the undo stack. Consider creating your own undo function that reverses what your add-in has done, and creating a UI for it in a task pane or ribbon.

Comment: @ismael's first suggestion would not weaken the undo stack at all. The behaviour he's describing his add-in is taking is similar to ours, and I'm assuming his users, like ours, are expecting to be able to undo, what appears to be an atomic change, atomically.